# Getting JSON decode error even after enclosing property name in double quotes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I try to make a post request so as test the login endpoint, I get "JsonDecodeError".

login view

```
class Login(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        data = str(request.data["json"])
        dd = json.loads(data)
        phone_number = dd["phone_number"]

        user = authenticate(phone_number=phone_number)
        if user is not None:
            token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            print(token[0])
            login(request, user)
            data = {
            'message': 'valid',
            'token': str(token[0])

            }
        else:
            data = {
            'message': 'invalid'
            }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: `request.data` is [already parsed content](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data). You can access it directly. i.e. `request.data['phone_number']`. If it nested: `request.data['json']['phonenumber']`. If for some reason request body is json, with field `json`, which contains another json as string - it looks strange and overcomplicated. Whole suggested request body:  `{"phone_number": "123"}`

Comment: @OlegRusskin I already did it that way you talked about, now I am getting a new error.  Error: "JSONDecodeError at /api/login/
Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Comment: Can you provide sample of post request body?

Comment: {"phone_number":"090201943"} @OlegRusskin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access [request.data](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data), drectly don't re-parse it with `json.loads()`.

Also, use more DRF options (request/response/etc) if it is DRF view (APIView), not Django ones.

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Login(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        phone_number = request.data.get("phone_number")
        user = None
        if phone_number:
            user = authenticate(phone_number=phone_number)
        if user:
            token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            login(request, user)
            data = {
                'message': 'valid',
                'token': str(token[0])
            }
            return Response(data)

        return Response(
            {'message': 'invalid'},
            status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Russkin